# ESP8266 with the MicroPython always reboots

Tags: esp8266, micropython

I've flashed the MicroPython into the NodeMSU board based on 12E chip and have used the `screen` command in the terminal on OS X to run the REPL. It works a few seconds and the REPL resets.

I have no idea where is the problem ( I can write a few commands when the all my work clears and I see the MicroPython console from scratch.

Answer (score 2):

without more information, this is a difficult issue to diagnose. basically, there are 4 possible causes of this behaviour:

1. power fluctuation causes the board to reset.
2. the board resets because the reset pin is physically set to gnd
3. the board resets because the reset pin is logically set to gnd
4. the function machine.reset() is called

steps to diagnose:

1. try a powered hub, separate power supply, different usb cable, different usb port to power your device and observe if the reset happens
2. inspect the board. see if there is a solder bridge between the reset pin and gnd (next to each other as seen on [this image](https://pradeepsinghblog.files.wordpress.com/2016/04/nodemcu_pins.png?w=612&zoom=2) or between the pins on the reset button
3. and 4) here you need to look at the code in boot.py and main.py; both located on the internal filesystem on your board. You can get those files using [webrepl](http://docs.micropython.org/en/v1.9.3/esp8266/esp8266/tutorial/repl.html) of using the following code:

   print(open('boot.py').read())
   print(open('main.py').read())

If you print the content here we can inspect it with you.

alternatively, try reflashing micropython [using the latest .bin from micropython.org](https://micropython.org/download#esp8266) and see if the clean version of micropython corrects the issue.